# Cannot register an unnamed wizard

Tags: delphi, teechart

I get this message when I open Delphi:

[image]

Seems to be an incompatibility between FastReports and TeeChart library.
Any idea how to fix this?

Possible [similar](https://www.steema.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14909&sid=9e16b527c3da6b54464d61c5636879b2&start=15) issue (reported by others).

---

Delphi 10.4.1 Pro
VCL
Win7 64bit
FastReports latest version (8 jan 2021)
TeeChart latest version, downloaded 2 weeks ago

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another version of the TeeChart library on your system somewhere?

Comment: Maybe something was preinstalled with Delphi? But usually I don't install many extra packages. How can I check that? Anyway, in registry, Known Packages, I see TeeChart listed/installed in a single folder (and one more time for FastReports folder).

Comment: Update: Opened a ticket with FastReports. They said: "Run FR recompile.exe and change TeeChart version". I will try that.

Comment: Update: Opened a ticket with FastReports. They said: "Run FR recompile.exe and change TeeChart version". I will try that  ||  Steema will only allow you to post questions on their forum if you pay for support.